# An internal server error has occurred in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, api, facebook

Getting Error :- "An internal server error has occurred"

I am tring to integrate Facebook and salesforce. I got Access token and i was tring to send GET request to Facebook Graph API as below.

```
public PageReference callprofile()
{        
 Pagereference p = ApexPages.currentPage();
    code = p.getParameters().get('access_token');
     if ((!(string.isBlank(code))))
        {               
          Http http =new Http();
            HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='+code );
            req.setmethod('GET');
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            ownprofile =res.getBody();
        }
        return p;
}
```

I am calling this method as below :

```
<apex:page controller="xxxxxxxx" action="{!callprofile}">
```

API call in Browser's new tab

```
https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Facebook_integration_homepage?access_token=EAAMCvxSocvQBADM9xGamO5Fod9ZCbs6r7HqxeJ41DPZCmy039N4RYKZB7javOQMX559QfM6JtGGXfWE2LhW
```

I tried to run this API call code in seperate Browser's Newtab. The API call is right. Its showing Perfect Output.

I tried to search for this type of error i found that its java's low level exception.

I tried to run the code by breaking it in chunks its working fine with perfect Output.

What Should be done to solve the error / exception ?

Comment: I would suggest at this stage you open a support case with Salesforce and log any error information that was provided to you at time of server error.

Comment: @TSmith From where I can open a support case with salesforce ?

Comment: If you head over to the [Partner Support](https://partners.salesforce.com) and log in, down the end of the page you will see "Submit a Case". Provide as much information as possible.

Comment: I had registered In partner support. i got a button for creating new case. by clicking that i got the categories like :
1) General 2)App Vendors (ISV) 3)Consulting Partners 4)ISV Technology 5)Salesforce Technology 6)Marketing Cloud.
Is there any category for developer type issue ?

Comment: Apex/API Development.

Comment: There is not anything like Apex/ Api Developement .